# Add content to list

Tags: c#

How can I proceed to add in the list the content of my foreach, without deleting the previous content?

```
lSave.Add(NextKey, new LSave());    

foreach (var container in corpse.containers)   
    lSave[NextKey].items = GetItems(container).ToList();
```

And the Structure

```
public Dictionary<uint, LSave> lSave = new Dictionary<uint, LSave>();
public class LSave
{
    public List<LItems> items;
    public LSave() { }
}
public class LItems
{
    public string name;
}

IEnumerable<LItems> GetItems(ItemContainer container)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I edit my message, sorry for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add more items to a specific key in the dictionary, try this:

```
foreach (var container in corpse.containers)
{
    LSave item;
    if (!lSave.TryGetValue(NextKey, out item))
    {
        item = new LSave();
        item.items = new List<LItems>();
        lSave.Add(NextKey, item);
    }

    item.items.AddRange(GetItems(container));
}
```

It adds an `LSave` to `NextKey` if needed and then adds the result of `GetItems(container)` to the `items` field of that `LSave`.

Comment: Thanks, i edit my message for more information

Comment: @crazyz: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, but since I didn't give enough information about the structure of my code, it doesn't work. My fault.

Comment: @crazyz: See my edit. I have not tested the code obviously, but it should at least give you the idea.

Comment: problem, items not instanced?

Comment: @crazyz: Yes, it is: `item.items = new List<LItems>();`